# Create 5-dimension input shape to 3d-CNN in python

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of 15 class with 460 images all. I want to enter every 8 sequences of images at the same time to the same CNN structure. I use conv3d to do that, but I'm confusing with input shape, it returns error. 
This is my model:

```
IMAGE_DIMS = (8, 460, 60, 60, 3)
data = []
labels = []

# loading images...
imagePaths = "dataset\\path"
listing = os.listdir(imagePaths)

for imagePath in listing:

    image_fold = os.listdir(imagePaths + "\\" + imagePath)
    for file in image_fold:
        im = (imagePaths + "\\" + imagePath + "\\" + file)
        image = cv2.imread(im)
        image = cv2.resize(image, (IMAGE_DIMS[2], IMAGE_DIMS[3]))
        image = img_to_array(image)
        data.append(image)

        label= imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
        labels.append(label)
# scale the raw pixel intensities to the range [0, 1]
data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)

# binarize the labels
lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) =     train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)


model = Sequential()
sample= IMAGE_DIMS[0]
frame=IMAGE_DIMS[1]
height = IMAGE_DIMS[2]
width=IMAGE_DIMS[3]
channels=IMAGE_DIMS[4]
classes=len(lb.classes_)

inputShape = (sample, frame, height, width, channels)
chanDim = -1

if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
    inputShape = (sample, frame, channels, height, width)
    chanDim = 1

model.add(Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3),    padding="same", batch_input_shape=inputShape))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2),    padding="same", data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2),    padding="same", data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# softmax classifier
model.add(Dense(classes))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
model.summary()

opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
  model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",   optimizer= opt, metrics=["accuracy"])

H = model.fit(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1,validation_data (testX,testY))
```

and this is my model summary:
[image]

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv3d_1_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (368, 60, 60, 3)
```

How can I fix the error, can anyone please help me, I will be thankful for any help. I know the problem with the input shape, the compiler refer to the `model.fit` step. I thing trainX, testX, trainY, testY must be in 5-dim, but I cannot able to that.

Comment: According to tensorflow site, input to a `conv3d` layer should be in the format of `[batch, in_depth, in_height, in_width, in_channels]`. batch is `batch_size`, `in_depth` should be `no_of_images_at_a_time` which is `8` in your case, `in_height` and `in_width` are `60` and `60`, `in_channels` is `3`. I can see this `in_depth` dimension is not there and the `batch_size` is rather large. This may cause the problem maybe? There's no point of doing `batch_input_shape=inputShape` if you are not feeding the images with `inputShape`.

Comment: @avin thank you for your reply. yes I do as you say. h, w, ch are 60,60,3 respectively. depth is 8. but I don't know what is batch? as I know the batch can't be filled, keras already known it, so I must input 4D tensor and keras treat it as a 5D. But it give me error that it is expect to have 5D tensor, when I place a no.of all dataset images as the attached code, it also give me error about the expected dimension to conv3d. It refer to the (model.fit) line, I suppose the problem with the train and test data, they must be 5d array. can you please help me in any thing?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to fit your model with 8 images which is called actually **batch**.  So when you call the method `model.fit()` set `batch_size = 8`. Another point that, I think,  you confused is about the input shape. If you would like to fit images to the network, your input shape is the  `height x width` of the image and the number of channels which is in your case RGB. So, the set `input_shape = (3, 60, 60)`. Please be aware of that the network structure does not includes the total number of images in it. Because the NN structure does not need to know what is the training number. When you fit the training images to the network it will just take a **batch** of it and does the training job. Lastly, Instead of using 3D convolution layer, you need to use 2D. Think it as a 2D frame that moves over the training image and it does the movement for each channel. Therefore, the frame size need to has a 2D shape, set it `(x, x)`. This frame is called kernel in [documents](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/).

The following code just an sample and has not been tested. I hope it helps to understand the structure:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 60, 60)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(number_of_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I did the structure of 2DCNN as you propose with 8 batch size, but I'm not sure if it do what I want or not. I want the input is 8 images (multi input CNN) at the same time, I thing this structure process images one by one and batch_size is the size of batch not the number of input(multi input), so I moved to 3DCNN. Is my idea is true or i'm wrong?? i.e Can I use batch_size =8 as a multi input ??

Comment: yes I did the same structure of 2DCNN but I don't know is it really do what I want. I cropped the images into 8 segments and I want to enter all of them (* segments) of the same image at the same time to the same structure (multi input CNN). If I use the 2DCNN structure and initialize batch_size 8 is benefit in my case? is batch_size and multi_input is the same concept? Can you please help me? I wish my idea is clear to understand.

Comment: I understand your problem now. In my opinion, you are right, you should use 3D convolution and pooling layers. However, again, the input shape will not include the number of training images. If I were you, I set the input shape (8, 60, 60, 3) and add 3d conv and pooling layers. Then you can call method.fit() with any number of training images as batch e.g 16, 32 or 64.

Comment: I will try that, thank you.